# Electrical eddy current visualization or simulation

Tags: electromagnetism

Eddy currents are induced in a metal plate when it experiences a changing magnetic flux. Is there a realistic visualization or simulation of eddy currents available? The only picture I found, on wikipedia, is a cartoon schematic.

Comment: That depends what You see as a "realistic visualisation". There are very convincing experiments. But You will never see the eddy currents, as You never saw some other electric current. What is the aim of the question? What is Your background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see accurate visualizations of (simulated) eddy currents in multiple papers. One example is:

- [Efficient Solvers for Nonlinear Time-Periodic Eddy Current Problems](http://www.asc.tuwien.ac.at/~schoeberl/wiki/publications/multiharmonic2.pdf)